# Representing sets on a complex number plane

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help represent the following sets on a complex number plane:

> [image]

• A: Is it $0≥Arg(z)≥π/3$?

Arg(z) = $-5π/6$, does that mean we only draw a line with the angle $-5π/6$ without coloring the shaded area?

• B: Should we draw a unit circle (with dashed lines), since the absolute value, $|z|$, is less than one? Shall I shade the region in the following interval $π/2 ≥ Arg(z) ≥ π/6$?

• D: Should I shade in the area between $|z| = 4$ and $|z| = 2$, but which angles should I shade between, does $Arg(z) > π/2$, is it $0 > Arg(z) > π/2$?

• E: Shall I shade in the interval $3π/4 > Arg(z) > π/2$ within $[-3, 3]$?

• D\E: Shall I shade in $4≥|z|≥3$, but I don't know in which range to shade there.

Comment: No, it is NOT "$0\ge Arg(z)\ge \pi/3$" because 0 is NOT larger than or equal to $\pi/3$!

Comment: Okay so Arg(z)≥π/3 ad infinitum? Until when do we shade?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the precise definition of $Arg(z)$. Is it the principal value?